# Python ругается на команду elif

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width: #фрагмент кода ниже
        def draw(self):
            self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
            pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
            if pos[1] <= 0:
                self.y = 2
                if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
                    self.hit_bottom = True
                    canvas.create_text(250, 120, text='Вы проиграли', font=('Courier', 30), fill='red')
                    if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
                        self.y = -2
                        if pos[0] <= 0:
                            self.x = 2
                            if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
                                self.x = -2
                                class Paddle:
                                    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
                                        self.canvas = canvas
                                        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
                                        start_1 = [40, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 200]
                                        random.shuffle(start_1)
                                        self.starting_point_x = start_1[0]
                                        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.starting_point_x, 300)
                                        self.x = 0
                                        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
                                        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)
                                        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
                                        self.started = False
                                        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Return>', self.start_game)
                                        def turn_right(self, event):
                                            self.x = 2
                                            def turn_left(self, event):
                                                self.x = -2
                                                def start_game(self, event):
                                                    self.started = True
                                                    def draw(self)
```

Comment: Примите ответ, если он вам помог(галочка около ответа)

Comment: Вы случаем не пытаетесь вставить многострочный текст в окно IDLE?

Comment: нет не пытаюсь,

Answer (score 2):

Синтаксис таков:

```
if <something>:
   <do_something>

elif <something_other>:
    <do_something_other>

else:
    <do_something_if_not_if_not_something_or_something_other>
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
else:
    pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
```

Comment: все равно пишет invalid syntax

Comment: Ниже ответил Victor Says Reinstate Monica, про синтаксис.

Я не учёл табуляцию в моём коде, возможно это сыграло роль. Проверь :)

Comment: @ТимофейТепляков Сейчас должно работать, внёс правку

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn Я ответил не ниже, а уже выше :)

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica Я удивлён, на сколько потрясающая аудитория у пайтона, примерно за 30 минут :D

Comment: Питон любимый язык огромного числа людей, а также у многих главный инструмент.

Comment: @ТимофейТепляков Скинь кусок кода, где ты используешь if, elif, else полностью

Comment: Сыграло роль неправильный синтаксис, а не табуляция.

Comment: @Эникейщик Теперь видно, автор прислал другой кусок кода изначально :)